# Search and Replace under linux?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I tried the following but not adding `''` this example

I want to replace `FILENAME_LOGIN` to `'login.php'`

Tried this:

```
grep -r "login.php" -l | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs sed -i 's/"login.php"/'login.php'/g'
```

However, it gives me `login.php` not `'login.php'`

Thanks

Comment: Untested, but try to escape the single quotes: `xargs sed -i 's/"login.php"/\'login.php\'/g'` - or double-escape: `xargs sed -i 's/"login.php"/\\'login.php\\'/g'`

Comment: You can't include single quotes in a single-quote delimited script, no matter how many times you try to escape them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `sed` for this:

```
sed -i -e "s/FILENAME_LOGIN/'login.php'/g" /your/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/FILENAME_LOGIN/'login.php'/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Yes, this will search in files in any subdirectory, nice! :)

Comment: it won't add single quotes around the text though.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/FILENAME_LOGIN/'\''login.php'\''/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Even something as simple as "You forgot to quote the `'` characters" would be a great improvement.